# Unable to open adobe reader

Tags: windows-10, adobe-reader

I am having trouble opening adobe reader. I thought it was the files at first, but then I tried to open the app itself to run updates and fix the installation. The app won't even open.

I tried fixing the app through programs and features, and I tried uninstalling and re-installing. None of it works.

What else should I try? Has anyone else had this problem?

I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I downloaded from the Adobe website about 6 months ago. The program was working prior to today. I'm using the app on Windows 10.

Comment: Workaround until it's fixed: try any of the other readers, e.g. lightweight, free, Sumatra from MS Store or other sites. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/sumatra-pdf/9pnjwv0hphzk?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: Is Sumatra equal to adobe reader? Or, would you say it's better?

Comment: Here is what I did to work around the issue until I can figure out the Adobe thing. The client already has a pro version of Nuance pdf converter, so I set that as his default for now. I could still use some help figuring out why Adobe won't open. I have not found any helps from Adobe support yet.

Comment: Personally, I prefer both Sumatra and free versionof PDF X-Change Viewer to Adobe's, but that's a matter of opinion. If Nuance works well for you, you probably don't need the Adobe tool... though it's puzzling why it no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall your current version (you said that you know how to do this) then get and install the latest version. Download from https://get.adobe.com/reader/

This will bypass the need to update or fix your old version

Comment: I've already been down this road. I uninstalled completely, then I went to the adobe website and re-installed from there. I also deleted the data files and the program files. Are there any other fixes you know of?

Comment: If you are comfortable with editing the registry you can try turning off  protectedMode. 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Privileged]
"bProtectedMode"=(0 = off; 1 = on)